# How to allow html tags in DataGrid BoundColumn cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net web forms app.
I want to be able add html tags inside `DataGrid` cell. Problem is `DataGrid` doesn't support `HtmlEncode` property for the `BoundColumn` .  And after i click update i have `System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException` error .
I understand that I could set `ValidateRequestMode` for the DataGrid or `ValidateRequest` for the whole page, but I want to set this property only for one column.
How can i allow to input HTML tags for a single column?

**UPDATE**: If if use ItemTemplate, this cell will not be able to edit from `OnEditCommand`. I need a way to make it editable like other cells.
My Grid:

```
     <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="MainGrid"    AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnEditCommand="MainGrid_EditCommand"  OnUpdateCommand="MainGrid_UpdateCommand" OnItemDataBound="MainGrid_ItemDataBound" OnSortCommand="MainGrid_SortCommand" AllowSorting="true"  >
            <Columns>  
             <asp:BoundColumn  HeaderText="Id" DataField="ID" /> 
             <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name"/> 
             <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Source" DataField="Source"/> 
             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Is Active" HeaderText="Is Active" /> 
             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" /> 
           <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Additional info" SortExpression="Additional info" > 
<ItemTemplate > 

        <asp:Literal Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Additional info") %>
                           runat="server"    ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" />

     </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="Photo Path"  HeaderText="Photo Path"/> 
            <asp:EditCommandColumn  EditText="Edit"  CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Edit"/>
            <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete"/> 

          </Columns>  
                    </asp:DataGrid>
```

Code :

```
protected void MainGrid_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    MainGrid.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;

    BindData();
}
```

Comment: Use TemplateFields.

Comment: @VDWWD its nice, but when i will click edit, it will not affect to this cell , i update my answer with explanation